# Ada - Operator subprogram

Tags: operators, ada

Create a subprogram of type operator that receives two integers and sends them back
the negative sum of them. I.e. if the sum is positive it will be
the result is negative or if the sum is a negative result
positive. Ex. 6 and 4 give -10 as a result and 2 and -6 give 4.

For instance:

```
Type in two integers: **7 -10**

The negative sum of the two integers is 3. 

Type in two integers: **-10 7**

The positive sum of the two integers is -3.
```

No entries or prints may be made in the subprogram.

So I attempted this task and actually solved it pretty easily using a function but when it came to converting it to an operator I stumbled into a problem.

This is my approach:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Test is

    function "+" (Left, Right : in Integer) return Integer is 
        Sum : Integer;
    
    begin
        Sum := -(Left + Right);
        return Sum;
    end "+";
       
    Left, Right : Integer;
       
begin
    Put("Type in two integers: ");
    Get(Left);
    Get(Right);
    Put("The ");
       
    if -(Left + Right) >= 0 then
        Put("negative ");
    else 
        Put("positive ");
    end if;
       
    Put("sum of the two integers is: ");
    Put(-(Left + Right));

end Test;
```

My program compiles but when I run it and type two integers it says:

```
raised STORAGE_ERROR: infinite recursion
```

How do I solve this problem using an operator? I managed to tackle it easily with the procedure- and function subprogram but not the operator. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Am I supposed to return Boolean instead? But even so, I still need to have a function that's -(Left + Right) and I'm not getting to work that way

Comment: Look sharply at the operator you have used...

Comment: I have, you are supposed to use it to add to integers in this case. I am adding the two inputs and then converting it to a negative value.

Comment: Try using a different operator symbol for producing the negative sum. Your solution tries to use the "+" symbol for both negative sums and positive sums, resulting in the infinite recursion message. The Ada addition operators are "+", "-" and "&". There is no pre-defined use of "&" for integers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the type system to solve this without using a new operator symbol.

As a hint, operators can overload on argument and return types. And a close reading of the question shows the input type is specified, but not the output type. So, how about this?

```
type Not_Integer is new Integer;

function "+" (Left, Right : in Integer) return Not_Integer is 
    Sum : Integer;

begin
    Sum := -(Left + Right);
    return Not_Integer(Sum);
end "+";
```

As the two "+" operators have different return types, there is no ambiguity between them and no infinite recursion.

You will have to modify the main program to assign the result to a `Not_Integer` variable in order to use the new operator.